# Evenly place divs in five vertical columns

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to create a dynamic layout consisting of five columns. In each column, items should be placed evenly on the vertical, starting from the left and ending at the right. If there for example was a total of 8 items, there would be 2 items in the first three columns, and 1 item in the two last columns.

Like this:

```
 _______ _______ _______ _______ _______                       _______
|#######|#######|#######|#######|#######|                     |       |
|#  1  #|#  3  #|#  5  #|#  7  #|#  8  #|                     |       |
|#######|#######|#######|#######|#######|                     |       |
|#######|#######|#######|       |       |                     |       |
|#  2  #|#  4  #|#  6  #|       |       |   #######           |       |
|#######|#######|#######|       |       |   #  x  # == item   |       | == column
|_______|_______|_______|_______|_______|   #######           |_______|
```

The problem I'm having is not with the CSS layout for this, but with the actual creation of the loop. I've managed to calculate how many items that would have to be placed in each column, by dividing the amount of items with the amount of columns.

Here's the loop so far:

```
<?php
...
// The Loop
if ($cards->have_posts()) {

    $length           = $cards->post_count;
    $column_amount    = 5;
    $items_per_column = $length / $column_amount;
    $items_per_column = round($items_per_column);
    $counter          = 0;

    if ($items_per_column < 1) {
        $items_per_column = 1;
    }

        echo '<div class="grid columns equal-height border-bottom">';

        while ($cards->have_posts()) {
            $cards->the_post();

            if ($counter % $items_per_column == 0) {
                echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
                echo '<div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-5 border-left no-padding">';
            }

            get_template_part("modules/column-item"); 

            if ($counter == $length) {
                echo '</div>'; 
            }

            $counter++;

        }
        echo '</div>';

    }

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

But this is not working since it's not placing the items one by one in the divs in their query order, but trying to force every column to consist of two items. And that eventually breaks the whole thing.

Does anybody know of any neat trick for achieving this?

Comment: I'd take another approach here. Trying to manage your rows and columns on the backend is likely more difficult than wrapping them all in one div,  then looping through, tagging them sequentially, and dong the row/column management entirely via CSS.

Comment: @RyanKozak Yeah, I was thinking about that as a last resort. The reason I wanted to do this the backend way is because the rest of the site is styled and structured with this grid framework. And to avoid differences in the layout by using a completely different markup, I thought it would be worth giving it a try. But yeah, you might be right.

Comment: @RyanKozak Do you know if it's possible to use the `column` CSS property without having the items breaking and continuing on the next column?

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of items ahead of time. Then, when it's getting to `$count - 1`, make sure that and `$count` get their own columns. My idea below could probably be optimized a bit, but this was demonstrating the basic idea, not providing a complete solution. Leave a comment if you don't understand what I'm getting at.

```
$columnCount = count($cards);
$i = 1;

while ($cards->have_posts()) {
            $cards->the_post();

            if($i == $columnCount || $i == ($columnCount - 1)){
              //create single item column
             }
            else ($counter % $items_per_column == 0) {
                echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
                echo '<div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-5 border-left no-padding">';
            }

            get_template_part("modules/column-item"); 

            if ($counter == $length) {
                echo '</div>'; 
            }

            $counter++;
            $i++;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out! Appreciate the effort, but I might be leaning towards trying this the CSS way instead as suggested above. But I'll give your example a try first. :)

Comment: Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I actually followed user Ryan Kozaks advice and solved this with CSS instead. Feels like it's the most effective way to not rely on the PHP loop for the layout, at least in this particular case.

I instead used a pretty standard way of looping through the posts, adding them with the class `.columns__item` to a container called `.columns`. I then took advantage of the `columns` property in CSS and did the following:

```
.columns {
    column-count: 5;
}

.column__item {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid; 
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid; 
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid; 
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid; 
    column-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

I'm a bit extra causious by using both `page-break-inside` and `break-inside` on the column items. What that essentially does is preventing the `.column__item` from breaking into several columns. This way the `.columns` gets an adaptive height depending on how many column items there are and sets it's height according to the tallest column. I probably just need the `column-break-inside`, but it was a bit unclear what the difference between the two was, so I went with both and it seems to work.